# How to install JasperReports as an Eclipse plugin with no internet connection?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports

I need to create a report in Java with Spring. So I need to install a plugin for `Eclipse`, more specifically `JasperReports` as a plugin. The problem is that I don't have online access to `Sourceforge` to download the plugin.

I read something like I can create a new plugin just using the jar files. But I'm facing the same problem, because I don't know how to download it or where I can get it.

Comment: is just a why to say other form to install the plugin.

Comment: can you download the jar files and the jasper file on another computer at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the files from another computer and put it in a usb. I guess if you have connection for stackoverflow, you might have enough for downloading files. The procedure is shown [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-eclipse)

what I used before: open Eclipse:

```
Help -> Install New Software... -> Add -> Archive....
```

- Another way: is listed on the [Eclipse documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins)

In Eclipse Kepler:

- you can also  add in the Eclipse plugins folder. You can start Eclipse with the `-clean` option to make sure Eclipse sees the new plugin after cleaning its cache.